# Pydlm confidence interval for the predictions

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting

Is there a way of getting the confidence interval for **pydlm** predictions? I have used both the functions *predictN* and *plotpredictN*- Both the functions return only the predictions and the variance but not the confidence intervals for them. Can we get something similar to Prophet model like "Yhat_upper" and "Yhat_lower" values for pydlm predictions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getInterval` function. Below is an example,

```
filteredCI_upper = pd.DataFrame(mydlm.getInterval(filterType='forwardFilter')[0])

filteredCI_lower = pd.DataFrame(mydlm.getInterval(filterType='forwardFilter')[1])
```

Comment: I have used this function but CI is not symmetric with regards to predictions and many times prediction does not belong to the confidence interval.